# JQuery not working in JSP page but javascript works fine

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I am facing issue while running a JSP page using tomcat server. I've included the `<script>` tag inside my JSP to add JQuery and my customscript JS file but unfortunately after the JSP page gets loaded JQuery doesn't work.

This is how I've included my JS file with JQuery code inside the JSP page:

```
<script src="js/customscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For Testing purpose whether this file gets included in JSP page I tried with putting just an alert and it works fine also I tried to put simple JQuery function as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("JQuery called");
});
```

This too works fine but when I put an `onclick` event  outside it doesn't work? Why?
Is there anything I am doing incorrect? Any suggestions?

**Thanks!**

Comment: $("#testClick").on('click',function(){ alert("JQuery called"); });
You need to attach an event with '.on' if you are writing outside the ready function.

Comment: javascript errors are caused by many reasons.  Could you please share the debug result from Developer Console

Comment: did you add jquery lib in your jsp page ?

Comment: Guys JQuery click() event works fine if I place it inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` but if I write it outside `ready` function it fails. @CaptainHere I tried with what u suggested it failed and even I tried this :

 `$("#btnExcel").click(function(){ alert("JQuery Ouside"); });`
but this too failed.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a event.preventDefault() to your click function.

HTML

```
    a href="#" id="myID class="myClass" onclick="functionClick(myEvent)"
```

JavaScript

```
    function myClick(myevent){
    myevent.preventDefault();
    // Your code
    );
    }
```